# Understanding about data type python

Tags: python, hex, reverse-engineering, type-conversion

Today I've started learn about reverse engineering. I met struc.pack(), but I dont know what \x12 meaning.

```
from struct import pack
pack('>I', 0x1337)
'\x00\x00\x137'
```

So \x137 is equal to 0x1337 (hex) in big-edian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'0x137'` is not a single byte, its actually two different bytes - `0x13` and `0x37` (or the character `'7'`) . The hexadecimal value for the ascii value of `'7'` is `0x37`, hence you get `0x137`. Example -

```
>>> hex(ord('7'))
'0x37'
```